# How do I select a class element based on its id in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple dynamically generated buttons with a class name of ".button". Each of these are given an unknown ID value used to uniquely identify them. In jQuery I must select one and alert the values.

```
<div class="button" id="3"></div>
```

The ID value is dynamically generated, therefore I do not know it. I'm new to jQuery but am basically looking for something like this:

```
$(".button").attr("id").val();
```

How do I target one button when there are many? Thanks!

EDIT:
I want to select whichever one the user clicks. The button in this case is a comment button. There is one for each "post". And I will change the ID to begin with a letter, as I am not using HTML5, whops. :)

Comment: *Which* one do you want to target? One at random, the third one, the first, the last? Other?

Comment: Another note, you should prefix your IDs unless you're using an HTML5 doctype, IDs cannot start with a number in HTML 4.

Comment: FYI numerical `id` attributes aren't valid.  The id must start with a letter. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: @Nick - which one? id's are supposed to be unique on a page.

Comment: @jmucchiello - Which `.button` element

Comment: @jmucchiello: but there are many buttons, OP doesn't have id. So the question Nick was asking is which of the `div.button` OP wants to access.

Comment: I want to select whichever one the user clicks. The button in this case is a comment button. There is one for each "post". And I will change the ID to begin with a letter, as I am not using HTML5, whops. :)

Comment: @Michael: this information belongs into the question, not the comment.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many .button divs are on the page. Each should have unique id attrs (if they have id attrs) and since his example specifies that he wants id=3 (pretend it is valid) then that is the specific one he wants. ID attributes are supposed to be unique page-wide. Since he is looking for id=3, you should be able to find it with just an id-selector which means (from what little I know of jQuery) you use #id.

Comment: @jmucchiello - I think you need to read the question again, he doesn't know the ID, they *are* unique and `3` was just an example.

Comment: @jmucchiello: *Each of these are given an **unknown** ID.* There is id, but OP doesn't know it. The only thing he knows is a certain button was clicked. It really is a very basic question.

Comment: @Nick,@SilentGhost - I know. Now. His original question made it sound like he wanted to know how to select an element. His edit changes the question completely. That's why I upvoted SilentGhost's answer as it actual tells you which button was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".button").click(function() { 
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and kindness to my post Silent. Your answer is concise and much appreciated. I have been using yahoo answers for years and this is my first post here, and wow. I will definitely become a regular contributor.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all of them using

```
$(".button").each(function(index) { 
    alert("index: " + index + " id: " + $(this).attr("id")); 
});
```

Comment: I was unaware of the each function. This could prove to be useful, thanks moi!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess `$('#id')` is sufficient.

I prefer the Mootools method: `$('id')` as `$` is just an alias for `getElementById`

Comment: As said in the comments above, he *doesn't know* the ID, so this approach doesn't work.

Comment: This answer was written before he edited the question to make clear what he wanted.

Comment: The [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3046758/revisions) still had: "The ID value is dynamically generated, therefore I do not know it", but alright :)

Comment: Hey, he could be dynamically generating the javascript too. So he would "know" the id. It wasn't very clear. But I'm done with it now.